# How to calculate probabilities from confusion matrices? need denominator, chars matrices

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, opennlp, confusion-matrix

[This paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/C/C90/C90-2036.pdf) contains confusion matrices for spelling errors in a noisy channel. It describes how to correct the errors based on conditional properties.

The conditional probability computation is on page 2, left column. In footnote 4, page 2, left column, the authors say: "The chars matrices  can  be   easily  replicated, and are therefore omitted from the appendix." I cannot figure out how can they be replicated!

**How to replicate them? Do I need the original corpus? or, did the authors mean they could be recomputed from the material in the paper itself?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the paper, you just need to calculate them using a corpus, either the same one or one relevant to your application.

In replicating the matrices, note that they implicitly define two different `chars` matrices: a vector and an n-by-n matrix. For each character `x`, the vector `chars` contains a count of the number of times the character `x` occurred in the corpus. For each character sequence `xy`, the matrix `chars` contains a count of the number of times that sequence occurred in the corpus.

`chars[x]` represents a look-up of `x` in the vector; `chars[x,y]` represents a look-up of the sequence `xy` in the matrix. Note that `chars[x]` = the sum over `chars[x,y]` for each value of `y`.

Note that their counts are all based on the 1988 AP Newswire corpus ([available from the LDC](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC93T3A)). If you can't use their exact corpus, I don't think it would be unreasonable to use another text from the same genre (i.e. another newswire corpus) and scale your counts such that they fit the original data. That is, the frequency of a given character shouldn't vary too much from one text to another if they're similar enough, so if you've got a corpus of 22 million words of newswire, you could count characters in that text and then double them to approximate their original counts.

Comment: if it is not the same corpus, then how can the probabilities be calculated? the numerator and the denominator should be "compatible" -- no? otherwise the division could yield very different probabilities depending upon the corpus for the numerator and the corpus for the denominator.

Comment: If you use a similar corpus (i.e. one of newswire text) of similar size, you can probably assume that characters and character sequences occur with roughly the same frequency as in their original corpus. (I'm looking around to see if the 1988 Newswire corpus is available for download anywhere, but you may end up having recalculate the other matrices as well.)

Comment: Looks like the 1988 data is part of the TIPSTER corpus available from the LDC: http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC93T3A

Comment: Thank you for the data link.  But re your comment about "similar corpus", the problem is that the paper does not give frequencies anywhere; it gives *counts*. To get frequencies from counts, you need the chars array based on the original corpus (I think). And if you have the frequencies then you don't need any other information any way. Am I right?

Comment: My reasoning is basically this: a similar corpus (e.g. same genre) should have similar character frequencies. They state that the 1988 AP Newswire corpus has ~44 million words, so if you use a corpus of 22 million words of newswire and double your counts, you might get a reasonable approximation.

Comment: that sounds reasonable if the total word count is factored in.  it does seem like a rather unfortunate choice on part of the authors to not include the chars matrices which are no bigger than the ones already included and would have helped the community so much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11895/discussion-between-dmh-and-agks-mehx)